# Quarkus Reactive PostgreSQL Vert.x - Collection of Long & in () queries

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, reactive-postgresql-client

I am trying to use a prepared query with a 'where xxx in ()' query using a Set of Long as parameter:

```
public static Multi<Item> findAll(PgPool client, Set<Long> ids) {
  Tuple parameter = Tuple.of(ids.toArray(new Long[]{}));
  // Tuple parameter = Tuple.wrap(new ArrayList(ids));
  return client.preparedQuery("SELECT id, name, properties FROM items where id in ($1)").execute(parameter)
      .onItem().transformToMulti(set -> Multi.createFrom().iterable(set))
      .onItem().transform(Item::from);
    }
```

But while the 'in' SQL query is supposed to handle multiple values, it does work when passing an array, throwing the following:

```
io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Parameter at position[0] with class = [[Ljava.lang.Long;] and value = [[Ljava.lang.Long;@1a074753] can not be coerced to the expected class = [java.lang.Number] for encoding.
```

Passing a single value works but it is not the purpose of the method:

```
  Tuple parameter = Tuple.of(1206756351360216067L);
```

What would be the correct way to handle the set of ids in order to return multiple rows ?

**Edit**

I ended up doing this:

```
        Tuple parameter = Tuple.of(ids.toArray(new Long[]{}));

        String query = "with values as (\n" +
                "select unnest(($1)::bigint[]) as id\n" +
                ")\n" +
                "select v.* from values vl " +
                "join items v on v.id = vl.id";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT id, name, properties FROM items where id = ANY($1)
```

And then you should be able to use a List/Set/Array parameter value.

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to use inverse of this criteria, essentially NOT IN clause? I tried using != ANY($1) but it only works if the passed list has only 1 value.

Comment: have you tried `NOT (id = ANY ($1))` ?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, that alternative did not work. I created a separate SO post with additional detail, if you could take a look, greatly appreciate it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509225/quarkus-hibernate-reactive-postgresql-not-in-clause

Comment: That option in fact worked. The error that I ran into was for a different query. Thanks for your help