# Quarkus Hibernate Reactive Postgresql NOT IN clause

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, reactive

I am trying to get a NOT IN clause working with Hibernate Reactive Postgres in Quarkus, and I tried the below combinations without any luck. Any Help is greatly appreciated.

The parameter passed is an Array of java.lang.Number and contains : [1, 2]

**Version 1**

```
SELECT count(1) FROM employees WHERE NOT (id = ANY ($1))
```

**Exception:**

```
io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT" (42601)
```

**Version 2:**

```
SELECT count(1) FROM employees WHERE  (id NOT IN ANY ($1))
```

**Exception:**

```
io.vertx.pgclient.PgException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ANY" (42601)
```

**Version 3:**

```
SELECT count(1) FROM employees WHERE  (id NOT IN ($1))
```

**Exception:**

```
io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Parameter at position[0] with class = [[Ljava.lang.Number;] and value = [[Ljava.lang.Number;@331e7075] can not be coerced to the expected class = [java.lang.Number] for encoding.
```

Java code to execute the query:

```
@Inject
PgPool client; 

----

client.preparedQuery(queryString).execute(Tuple.tuple(params));
```

where queryString contains the above mentioned query, and  params is a Number[] with the value [1,2]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the Java code you use to execute the query.

Comment: @GavinKing Thanks for looking into this, I edited the post to include the relevant java code

Comment: For anyone looking for answer, the first version in fact was working. The exception that I was running into was for a query that runs after that was built differently.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to bind the parameter as a PostgreSQL array? I don't know if the Vertx driver supports that, but you can bind it as string and cast in the SQL like:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM employees WHERE id <> ALL($1::int[])
```

and bind the value as String `[1,2]`